# How to produce GeoJSON from a set of Geofields without a single point error?

Tags: views

I'm getting an error from a geoJSON view

```
Exception: Cannot construct a LineString with a single point in LineString->__construct() (line 18 of /vendor/itamair/geophp/lib/geometry/LineString.class.php).
```

Edit - possibly this bug https://www.drupal.org/project/views_geojson/issues/3332457

The purpose of the view is to list geoJSON from the content that matches the criteria. Each content item has a Geofield with a POLYGON() pasted into it

[image: Geofield polygon]

A view has been created.

[image: GeoJSON view configuration]

The style plugin formatting is

[image: GeoJSON style plugin formatting is]

The polygon field configuration is

[image: GeoJSON field configuration]

This is a migration from drupal-7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by this bug  https://www.drupal.org/project/views_geojson/issues/3332457 and solved by patching the module.